# T-SQL Find matching rows based on BIT parameter values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that returns rows within a person table that have the same value for particular columns. I want the stored procedure to accept parameter values such as `@match_on_forenames BIT` and `@match_on_surname BIT`. So for example `EXEC find_matching @match_on_forenames 1, @match_on_surname 1` would find rows in the table where the forenames and surname fields match, obviously not matching against itself.

I have a stored procedure similar to :

```
ALTER PROC get_matching_records
    @match_on_forenames BIT,
    @match_on_surname BIT
AS
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.forenames, p.surname
FROM 
    person p
WHERE       
    EXISTS 
      (
            SELECT 
                p1.forenames, p1.surname
            FROM 
                person p1                                                                   
            WHERE                                                                                                                            
                (((@match_on_forenames = 1 AND p.forenames = p1.forenames AND p.id <> p1.id)) OR @match_on_forenames = 0)
                AND (((@match_on_surname = 1 AND p.surname = p1.surname AND p.id <> p1.id)) OR @match_on_surname = 0)
                )
```

Soon as I introduce the `OR @match_on_forenames` the performance of the query becomes very poor.

Any ideas how I would best approach this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is your logic:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM person p1                                                                   
              WHERE                                                                                                                            
                (((@match_on_forenames = 1 AND p.forenames = p1.forenames AND p.id <> p1.id)) OR @match_on_forenames = 0)
                AND (((@match_on_surname = 1 AND p.surname = p1.surname AND p.id <> p1.id)) OR @match_on_surname = 0)
             )
```

If it is fast without the `or`, then three conditions might solve the problem:

```
WHERE (@match_on_forenames = 1 and @match_on_surname = 1 and
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM person p1                                                                   
               WHERE (p.forenames = p1.forenames AND p.id <> p1.id) AND
                     (p.surname = p1.surname AND p.id <> p1.id)
              )
      ) OR
      (@match_on_forenames = 0 and @match_on_surname = 1 and
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM person p1                                                                   
               WHERE (p.surname = p1.surname AND p.id <> p1.id)
              )
      ) OR
      (@match_on_forenames = 1 and @match_on_surname = 0 and
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM person p1                                                                   
               WHERE (p.forenames = p1.forenames AND p.id <> p1.id) 
              )
      )
```

Each of the `exists` clauses should be fast, based on your observation that the simpler query was faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and that does work. But apologies I did not make this clear at all in my initial post.  I could add more parameters values to match on. For example date of birth or email address. As soon as you get more than two parameters the solution above becomes very hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid having OR in my SQL statements
Here is what I would do, using a JOIN on the same table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
p.forenames, p.surname
FROM 
person p
inner join person pmatch on
    pmatch.id <> p.id
    and
    case when @match_on_forenames =1 then pmatch.forenames else p.forenames end = p.forenames
    and 
    case when @match_on_surname =1 then pmatch.surname else p.surname end = p.surname
```